# SQL count one row if many exist

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

I have what I think is a pretty standard Postgres SQL problem. I can explain it, just can't program it.

I have 4 rows that have unique account IDs. Each of these rows shares the same longitude and latitude values, but their physical addresses differ (apartment 1A, apartment 2B.....). Each account has status of active or inactive. Each account either gets or does not get HBO.

This data is all derived from a single table. My condition is this: 
Grouping by latitude, longitude and the name of the borough, loop the data and count one row where every account is inactive and at least one of the accounts is still getting HBO.

So if there are 4 accounts at the same lng/lat, 3 are inactive but 1 is still active, the record is **skipped**.

If there are 4 accounts at the same lng/lat, 4 are inactive, none get HBO, the record is **skipped**.

If there are 4 accounts at the same lng/lat, 4 are inactive, one still gets HBO, the record is **counted**.

UPDATE:
I need this as a count by town. I just used the lat/lng to confirm that the logic was correct and it is. The final result I'm looking for is this:

```
Borough | Count
---------------------
Bronx      50
Queens     12
```

Comment: Hi. What parts are you able to do? How much of the necessary info can you get via queries or in one query? Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Something like this
`SELECT "MasterListMN"."LATITUDE", "MasterListMN"."LONGITUDE"  
FROM "MasterListMN"  
WHERE "account_part_1" = 'INACT'  
AND "account_part_2" = 'INACT'  
AND "MasterListMN"."GETS_HBO" = 'TRUE'  
GROUP BY "MasterListMN"."LATITUDE", "MasterListMN"."LONGITUDE"`  

INACT is inactive.

Comment: Your specification is unclear. Are you asking to get lat/long where at least 1 account has hbo no matter if the account is active or not?

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your post, not comments.

Comment: @Krishna
No, I'm asking to count a row if all accounts at that lat/lng are inactive but AT LEAST one of them are still getting HBO. And I need to total that by the borough that lat/lng is found in. The borough is it's own column so no need to have any geocoding involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the lat/long pairs using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT ml."LATITUDE", ml."LONGITUDE"
FROM "MasterListMN" ml
GROUP BY ml."LATITUDE", ml."LONGITUDE"
HAVING SUM( ("account_part_1" = 'INACT' AND "account_part_2" = 'INACT')::int) = COUNT(*) AND
       SUM( (ml."GETS_HBO" = 'TRUE')::int) > 0;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I had played with a variation of it, but was getting too many rows. Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you would like to filter rows where inactive count = 4 and count of active hbo account > 0. I count the number of inactive and hbo accounts separately and filter rows accordingly. Similar to Gordon's solution.

```
SELECT lat, lon
FROM test
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_active THEN 1 END) = 0 
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN has_hbo THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

After this, you can group by borough and take the count. Here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/74381/1/0).

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. So the number of inactive accounts does not matter. What matters is that ALL accounts with the same lat/lng are inactive. 4 is just a number. There could be 20, we don't know.

So in order for a row to be counted, ALL accounts at that lat/lng must be inactive and AT LEAST one of those accounts is still getting HBO. If 20 records meet this criteria, it still should only count as 1 row since they are all at the same lat/lng. 

And then that total count needs to be grouped by borough, (Queens, NYC, Bronx, Westchester). Hope that makes more sense? Thank you!